# String manipulation Bash-Extensions

Tags: bash

In my script I'm trying to take a string, then output the extension of a string if it has one. So essentially I take the basename of a file, then output anything that comes after a period.

What's the syntax to do something like this?

For example

```
dotcutter.sh
file=testfile.jpg
```

the script should output .jpg

EDIT:

I've solved my problem now with:

```
file=$(basename "$1" )
stub=${file%.*}
echo ${file#"$stub"}
```

Which reduces my argument to a basename, thank you all.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/grabbing-the-extension-in-a-file-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ file=testfile.jpg
$ echo ${file##*.}
jpg
$ file=testfile.ext1.ext2
$ echo ${file##*.}
ext2
$ file=noextension
$ echo ${file##*.}
noextension
```

Notice that it doesn't work if the file has no extension. If that's important then try this two-step solution:

```
$ file=testfile.ext1.ext2
$ stub=${file%.*}
$ echo ${file#"$stub"}
.ext2
```

Or this regex-based one, which will only call `echo` if there's actually an extension. (`&&` is shorthand for "if then".)

```
$ regex='(\.[^.]*)$'
$ file=testfile.ext1.ext2
$ [[ $file =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
.ext2
$ file=noextension
$ [[ $file =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

See also:

- [basename(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)
- [dirname(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)
- [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073): How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? How can I get a file without its extension, or get just a file's extension?]

Comment: Could you explain for me, what specifically each part of
  
  `$ stub=${file%.*}`
    `$ echo ${file#"$stub"}`

does?

Comment: @BernieMacinflor The first line deletes the extension `.*` and stores just the file name in `$stub`. The second part deletes `$stub` from `$file`, which leaves the extension to be echoed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Bash and the syntax always seems very random and confusing.

Comment: @BernieMacinflor Sure, here to help! For more details look up "Parameter Expansion" in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
file=testfile.jpg
echo .${file#*.}
```

That use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: That only removes up to the first period, if there are more than one in the file name. Use `${file##*.}`.

Comment: Typically extensions have only one period. Moreover, this is what OP asked.

Comment: I'm thinking of file names like 'foo.tar.gz'. Is the extension 'gz' or 'tar.gz'?